# name hover image with flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

hello everyone
I have a flex-container and inside i have flex item for each image i have on database.
I want do hover images and show the name of the image.
I have try different ways but in all of them i lost the responsive from flex container and flex images
what i really want is when hover, dark images and show name in white letter, but if hover and show name in bottom of image, is also good
HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
                <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE estado = 1";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                // output data of each row
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $id_evento =  $row['id_evento'];
                    $nome =     $row['nome'];
                    $descricao =  $row['descricao'];
                    $imagem =  $row['imagem'];
                    $data =  $row['data'];
                    $local =  $row['local'];

                ?>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal_<?php echo $id_evento; ?>">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="flex-item">
                                <?php echo '<img src="backoffice/upload/' . $imagem . '" alt="' . $nome . '" class="grid-image">'; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
```

CSS:

```
    .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 50%;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.modalt {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.flex-item:hover {
    border: 3px solid black;
    opacity: 1;
}

.flex-item .grid-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.image-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with position absolute to get title in position with hover effect

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 23%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #000;
}

.item:hover .overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/25/21/14/woman-1353211_1280.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/25/21/14/woman-1353211_1280.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/25/21/14/woman-1353211_1280.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/25/21/14/woman-1353211_1280.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/25/21/14/woman-1353211_1280.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/25/21/14/woman-1353211_1280.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's great @TiagoNunes. Would you like to mark this as the correct answer. :)